# Booleans as checkboxes and saving the form

Tags: django

I have created a OnetoOne model for some user preference checkboxes.  This is mapped to the User, and using signals I create it when the user is created.  Here is what I have so far:

Model:

```
class DateRegexes(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prefix_1 = models.NullBooleanField()
    prefix_2 = models.NullBooleanField()
    prefix_3 = models.NullBooleanField()
    prefix_4 = models.NullBooleanField()
    prefix_5 = models.NullBooleanField()
    prefix_6 = models.NullBooleanField()
    prefix_7 = models.NullBooleanField()
    prefix_8 = models.NullBooleanField()
    prefix_9 = models.NullBooleanField()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_date_regexes(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        DateRegexes.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_date_regexes(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.date_prefs.save()
```

Form:

```
class DatePreferenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DateRegexes`
```

View:

```
@login_required
def set_date_preferences(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DatePreferenceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        date_prefs = get_object_or_404(DateRegexes, user=request.user)
        form = DatePreferenceForm(instance = request.user.date_prefs)
    return render(request, 'set_date.html', {'form': form})
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Date Preferences{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></p>
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
      <div>here {{ field }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Set</button>
    </form>
  </div>
{% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

When I execute this, the first thing that happens is that the expected checkboxes that are filled in according to their previously selected preferences, I get a bunch of dropboxes that each say:
"Unknown", "Yes", "No".

1) How can I get it show html checkboxes instead of the dropboxes?

2) When I submit the form I get:

```
IntegrityError at /db/set_date_preferences/
NOT NULL constraint failed: db_dateregexes.user_id
```

Which I understand that it is having trouble associating my form to the logged in user, but I'm not sure what the right way to associate this should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a `NullBooleanField` which can have 3 values: `None`, `True` or `False`. So the default widget to render such a field is a dropdown. If you want a checkbox you should decide what you want `None` to map to and override the fields in the `DatePreferenceForm` to be a `BooleanField`.

Second, since every `user` already has `prefs` you should initialise your form with the correct instance, even in the `POST` case. I don't really understand how your `form` can be valid since `user` is a required field (you should really exclude it from the form).

```
class DatePreferenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DateRegexes
        exclude = ['user']

# View
def set_date_preferences(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DatePreferenceForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.date_prefs)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # would be good practice to redirect to a success page here
    else:
        date_prefs = get_object_or_404(DateRegexes, user=request.user)
        form = DatePreferenceForm(instance = request.user.date_prefs)
    return render(request, 'set_date.html', {'form': form})
```